# How to using character functions like "like" in Microsoft Azure Table Storage Query Editor?

Tags: azure-storage

I have a table with a lot of data that I don't need, but I have to save that, however to do my job i need only some data.
so, to limit the amount of data that my query will return I have to use a filter to not get some files like the strings .js, .css, .log etc.

I'm using the "Microsoft Azure Explorer - Azure Table Storage - Query Editor" to do this, but I don't know how to use a function like SQL function "like" to filter that strings.

follow a example of data that i don't need in my return:
lg.folha.views.demonstrativodemedias.editar.min.css
27042018_144634_536_6A2FAE_AMB..xml

is it possible to filter that files using only the query builder options?

Query Builder Options

[image]

Query builder documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Querying-Tables-and-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Anchor_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fro now azure table doesn't support wildcard query. You could get it from here:[Filtering on String Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Querying-Tables-and-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN#filtering-on-string-properties).

> Note that the Table service does not support wildcard queries.

So you have to use `eq, ne, gt, ge, lt, le` these operators.

You could use `property ge 'test'  and RowKey lt 'test~'` to get query entities whose property starts with `test`.

Answer (score 1):

So, the Azure Table service doesn't support the function like, so I did an application in C# to do this.
doing that I solved two problems: 
1 - The like function - I created a function to exclud the worong files.
2 - the excel line limit - Excel have a limit of 1.048.576 and some of my stracts return more than this, so a did a function to split the list in N Excel's File.